No hint path defined for View Custom Module. from Laravel 11
created a custom Module in Laravel 11 and created blade file in Views folder and call the file in the controller. The return statement like   return view('Venue::index');
But it shows error like No hint path defined for [Venue].
So I added the code  $this->loadViewsFrom('Modules/Venue/Resources/views', 'Venue'); in VenueServiceProvider
And I also added the below code in view.php file,
'paths' => [
    resource_path('views'),
    resource_path('Modules/Venue/Resources/views'),
],

Please help me to solve the issue

are you using any package ? e.g nwirdart Module ?

Make sure you have registered custom service provider in bootstrap/providers.php
<?php

return [
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\VenueServiceProvider::class,
];

and
Suppose Modules folder in root directory then you have to define load view from like below in service provider boot method
 $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../../Modules/Venue/Resources/views', 'venue');

so you can access the below
 return view('venue::demo');

Ref: Views
